# Moving Magento 2 to local system perform extremely slow

Tags: magento-2.1

I have developed a custom theme using magento 2 and I have deployed it in a shared hosting one year ago. Meanwhile I've did multiple updates in my local computer (Mac using AMPPS server) and I deployed them using git to production.

Recently I decided to export the entire production environment and deploy it in my local computer in order to copy historical data about products, orders, users etc.
After importing the database and local folder structure the website started working extremely slow in my local machine. By slow I mean that it takes more than 4-5 minutes for switching between pages for both frontend and backend.

I tried a lot of things last couple of days - I was playing with the cache, i was changing the modes between developer and production, I tried to switch on and off the css/javascript merging, I build everything with grunt, I even tried to install a new MAMP server and run the website under nginx, but nothing helped.

Can someone help me to find a solution of the problem?

Comment: What are your specs? What is the resource usage? Did u try a service for caching, e.g Redis or Memcached ? Sessions can be cached also

Comment: I am using macOS 2.5 GH i7, 16 GB  RAM. The problem is the CPU usage,  httpd service takes 99% CPU when I switch pages in magento admin panel. I did not try Redis or Memcached, I will try to add it, but this is not the main issue because a few days ago before moving the folder structure and database from production everithing was working fine, so I guess it is some configuration or data problem.